# DNS server forward all queries except the queries for reverse DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, forwarding, reverse-dns

I would like to set up DNS server(bind) on debian. Which will forward all queries to google, except the queries to reverse DNS for specified zone.

I would like to respond queries for group of hosts named "clients" on my server,  and all the others queries relay to google DNS.

How to specific this configuration in named.conf.options file ? Where did I make a mistake?

here's my syntax:

```
acl clients {

10.10.10.0/24; ##example ip
localhost;
localnets;
};

options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";
         recursion yes;
         allow-query { clients; };

         forwarders {
                8.8.8.8;
                8.8.4.4;
         };

        auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
        listen-on-v6 { any; };

        zone "clients" {
        type master;
        forward no;

};

};
```

Regards

Comment: Really not sure what you are trying to do here, but `zone` blocks don't belong inside the `options` block.

Comment: Not sure, but it could be that constructing a db, and a zone, files for the required specified zone, is your 1st step. And then using views to limit the private zone to your clients. If this is indeed a possible solution, I hope you will post here all the details.